# How to solve MLE when noise variance is made learnable rather than fixed?

Tags: regression, bayesian

I saw some machine learning code assuming that variance of gaussian noise is a learnable parameter in linear regression problem. I'm wondering how is this solved theoretically?

Below you see typcial MLE derviation of linear regression. Noise (epsilon) is assumed to have fixed std which is sigma squared, what if we learened it just like w? what is sigma(x) ?

[image]

Comment: Hi: if you wanted to learn the variance, one way is to give it a prior and then update the posterior each time a new observation came in. See "Dynamic Linear Models" by West and Harrison for a more in-depth discussion of this approach which is really the state space approach.

Comment: @mlofton Wouldn't that then not be MLE, maybe MAP?

Comment: @Dave Exactly. I don't want to go Bayesian, I'm using MLE, I want to pick variance that varies with x, just like y varies with x.

Comment: @Dave I think the solution is to assume y = wx + epsilon, where epsilon is normal with variance = w2 * x. I.e. I'm assuming there's linear change with x, and I want the slope. Does that make sense? solution would be easy extension.

Comment: @Dave: I'm not sure what it would be called as far as an estimator but you're right that it's not an MLE. I'm not sure about obtaining MLE by learning since the likelihood is tricky. I'll stay out of this discussion and apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you can find the solution within the framework of the generalized linear mixed model. For instance, in the R package *nlme*, you can estimate heteroscedastic variances as a function of other model variables and they do it using a MLE.

Maybe you can go in this direction for a solution. This reference looks promising:
https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-22747-4_5

(Sorry for paywall but I could not find a similarly exhaustive treatment that is open.)